# Simplifying $\frac{\omega\sin(\omega t)\tan(\omega{t})+\omega(\cos(\omega t)+1)\sec^2(\omega t)}{(\cos(\omega t) +1)^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I simply this :
$$
\dfrac{{\omega}\sin \left( {\omega} {t}\right) \tan \left( {\omega}{t}\right) +\omega \left( \cos \left( \omega t\right) +1\right) \sec ^{2}\left( \omega t\right) }{\left( \cos \left( \omega t\right) +1\right) ^{2}}
$$

To become this :
$$
\dfrac{\omega \left( -\cos ^{2}\left( \omega t\right) +\cos \left( \omega t\right) +1\right) }{1+\cos \left( \omega t\right) }
$$

Comment: You might want to double-check some of your `w`s and `\omega`s. That said ... Please always include what you've tried and/or where you got stuck in a problem. This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your current level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to make a poor impression in this regard, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Expand the $\tan$ and $\sec$, multiply the leftmost term by $\cos/\cos$, expand the 1, factor the $(1+\cos)$, expand the $\sin^2$, and voila--

Comment: @Angelica could you make the steps clearer? I don't get what you mean by multiplying the leftmost term by cos/cos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\dfrac{\omega\sin \left( \omega t\right) \tan \left( \omega{t}\right) +\omega \left( \cos \left( \omega t\right) +1\right) \sec ^{2}\left( \omega t\right) }{\left( \cos \left( \omega t\right) +1\right) ^{2}},
\\
\sec(\omega{t})=\frac{1}{\cos(\omega{t})},\quad\tan(\omega{t})=\frac{\sin(\omega{t})}{\cos(\omega{t})},\implies
\\
\implies\dfrac{\omega\sin \left( \omega t\right) \tan \left( \omega{t}\right) +\omega \left( \cos \left( \omega t\right) +1\right) \sec ^{2}\left( \omega t\right) }{\left( \cos \left( \omega t\right) +1\right) ^{2}}=\frac{\omega\frac{\sin^{2}(\omega{t})}{\cos(\omega{t})}+\omega\left(\frac{\cos(\omega{t})+1}{\cos^{2}(\omega{t})}\right)}{\left(\cos\left(\omega{t}\right)+1\right)^{2}}=
\\
=\frac{\omega\frac{\sin^{2}(\omega{t})\cos(\omega{t})}{\cos^{2}(\omega{t})}+\omega\left(\frac{\cos(\omega{t})+1}{\cos^{2}(\omega{t})}\right)}{\left(\cos\left(\omega{t}\right)+1\right)^{2}}=
\frac{\omega(2\cos(\omega{t})-\cos^{3}(\omega{t})+1)}{\bbox[lightgreen]{\cos^{2}(\omega{t})}(\cos(\omega{t})+1)^{2}}.\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
If we will multiply that we must get on the expression $\frac{(1+\cos(\omega{t})}{(1+\cos(\omega{t})}$, therefore, the result will be:
$$
\dfrac{\omega \left( -\cos ^{2}\left( \omega t\right) +\cos \left( \omega t\right) +1\right) }{1+\cos \left( \omega t\right) }=\frac{\omega\left( -\cos ^{2}\left( \omega t\right) +\cos \left( \omega t\right) +1-\cos^{3}(\omega{t})+\cos^{2}(\omega{t})+\cos(\omega{t})\right)}{(1+\cos(\omega{t}))^{2}}=
\\
=\frac{\omega\left(1-\cos^{3}(\omega{t})+2\cos(\omega{t})\right)}{(1+\cos(\omega{t}))^{2}}.\qquad\qquad(2)
$$
As we can see in $(2)$ the multiplier $\bbox[lightgreen]{\cos^{2}(\omega{t})}$ is absent, therefore, the misprint takes a place.